# Declaring my object as 'extern' gives "storage class specified" error

Tags: c++, object, extern

I have 3 classes - GLWidget, Window and rules. Window creates an object of GLWidget called 'm_glWidget' which I am trying to access from the class rules. I have tried using 'extern' and changing things up but nothing seems to make it work. The closest I have got is a single error which says "storage class specified for 'm_glWidget'" but I am unsure on what this means. This is my code:

Window.h

```
#include "glwidget.h"
#include "rules.h"

class GLWidget; class rules;

class Window : public QDialog, public Ui::frmMain
{
    Q_OBJECT;

public:

    Window(QWidget *parent = 0);

    rules *gameRules;
    GLWidget *m_glWidget;
```

Window.cpp

```
#include "rules.h"
#include "glwidget.h"

class rules; class GLWidget;

using namespace std;

Window::Window(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent)
{

    m_glWidget = new GLWidget;
    gameRules = new rules;
```

rules.h

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "glwidget.h"

class rules{

public:

    rules();

    extern GLWidget *m_glWidget;
```

rules.cpp

```
#include "window.h"
#include "glwidget.h"

using namespace std;

rules::rules(){
}

void rules:: print(){

    cout << m_glWidget->x << endl;
}
```

Comment: `extern` cannot be applied to class members.

Comment: Okay thanks. Any suggestions on another way off accessing the variable in GLWidget from rules?

Comment: As usually, add a reference to Window instance in rules.

Comment: @TomStock: That depends what it's supposed to be. Is it a member of `rules`? Then remove the `extern`. Is it the member of `Window`? Then don't redeclare it, include the `Window` definition where you need it and access it as `some_window.m_glWidget`. If you need it to be independent of any `Window` object, then it should be `static`, accessed as `Window::m_glWidget`.

Comment: @TomStock either you make it static and access it via `rules::m_glWidget` or you don't use additional qualifiers and find some instance of `rules` for example `g_rules.m_glWidget`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "glwidget.h"

class rules{

public:
    rules(GLWidget *glWidget)
        : m_glWidget(glWidget)
    {
    }

    GLWidget *m_glWidget;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seemed to solve that problem, however for some reason it now doesn't like the object of 'rules' that I made in Window, called 'gameRules'. I get the error, "no matching function for call to rules::rules()'.

Comment: @TomStock it sounds like you defined something like `rules myrule;` which does not give constructor arguments to match what you provided in the class.  Your only ctor requires a `GLWidget*`.  You should brush up on C++ as it's different from what you ar3 used to, Ithink.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is very different to what I am used too. I have tried `gameRules = new rules(GLWidget*);` and it returns the error 'expected primary-expression before '*' token'. I assume I have put in the wrong parameter?

Comment: That's not C++ syntax, and if you were ready to write this you'd know it thf's jcdke nonce.  Get a C++ primer book, or a local in-person tutor.